# Creating an else condition in a loop if string does not exist in an array

Tags: java

The output i need

> enter name: john

> name not found in array

Here is my pseudocode

```
//ask for name
System.out.print("enter name")
name = sc.nextLine()

//loop to check if name exists in my array
for (int count = 0; count < arrayofnames.length; count++)
{ 
    if (name.equals(arrayofnames[count]))
    { code to be executed if name is found in arrayofnames }
}
```

I tried putting an else/else if condition after the if but it executes the code arrayofnames.length times. How do I only make it print something like "name not found in array" only once then break?

Comment: so add `break` in `if` block?

Comment: the if block only checks if the name exists in an array it doesnt check if the name DOES NOT exist in the array

Comment: @AngeloMiguelLicsi The `for` loop checks if the name exists in the array. But you don't know until you check **everywhere** in the array.

Comment: Do the names need to be in an array? If you store them in a `Set`, you can check using the `contains()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a flag, which you can test after the loop

```
System.out.print("enter name")
name = sc.nextLine()

boolean found = false;

for (int count = 0; count < arrayofnames.length; count++)
{ 
    if (name.equals(arrayofnames[count]))
    { 
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) System.out.println ("Not found");
```

Comment: i love you. this solved it. not really familiar with booleans lol

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "jhn";
        String[] arrayofnames = {"john", "tomer", "roy", "natalie"};
        IsName(name, arrayofnames);

        
    }
    public static void IsName(String _name, String[] _arrayofnames){
        boolean a = false;
        for (String name : _arrayofnames) {
            if(name == _name){
                System.out.println("name is in the array");
                a = true;
            }
        }
        if(!a){
            System.out.println("name is not in the array");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by putting your `String[] arrayOfNames` into an `ArrayList<>` and simply checking if the `ArrayList<>` contains the name given by the user.

```
String[] arrayOfNames = {"Angelo", "David", "John"};
String name = "Angelo"; //the name given by the user

ArrayList<String> newArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfNames));
//check too see if the ArrayList contains the name
if (newArray.contains(name))
    System.out.println("Name found in array");
else
    System.out.println("Name not found in array");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code more compact, you can also use Streams to check if any element of the array equals the given String like this:

```java
boolean found = Arrays.stream(arrayofnames).anyMatch(n -> n.equals(name));

if(found) {
  //code to be executed if name is found in arrayofnames 
}
```